# jqueryui tooltips fails to close when using ajax callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I've encountered an issue where using an ajax call with jQueryUI tooltip causes the tooltip to fail to close if you select multiple instances.

I've demonstrated it here, http://jsfiddle.net/MHptk/11/

```
var html = '';
var testbox = $("#testid"); //div element
for (var i=0; i<25; i++) {
html += '<a href="#" title="test!">test!</a><br />';
}

testbox.html(html);

testbox.tooltip(
    {tooltipClass:'preview-tip',
     content: function(callback) {
         $.ajax({url: '/echo/html/',
                 data: {
                     html: 'woop!',
                 },
                 method: 'post',
                 success: function(data) {
                     callback(data);
                 },
         });
     }, 
    });
```

Roll your mouse quickly over the links and you'll see the tooltips fail to close. In my real life example, I am creating a table with a jquery ajax call which contains multiple  links that, themselves, will make an ajax request. I also tried using the open: to set content but the same issue occurred.

For a workaround, I think i can just populate the title attr directly when creating the table but this isn't suitable given the highly volatile nature of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think just the large number of links so close together coupled with the ajax call is causing the issue.  If you spread them out a little I don't see the same issue. That is a lot of ajax calls firing in rapid succession.

I just inserted a `<p>no link</p>` into your fiddle to give it more room

[new fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/oumichaelm/MHptk/13/)

Comment: Even in your example, I still have multiple tooltips up. Is there a known issue/bug here? If it's known, I can happily wait until a new version is released. Otherwise, it seems like an annoying but mostly missable bug

Comment: I don't think they thought about that kind of use case.  It seems like there should be a better way to retrieve the data.  Perhaps you could request all the tooltips for a set to be downloaded and saved in an element. This would be much more efficient than allowing the user to fire 20-30 ajax request per second. At the least save the response so a new ajax doesn't fire for the same element over and over.

Comment: It is a bit evil but thankfully the server is local and I keep the php request latency quite low. However, I think I'll follow through with just caching all the data in the tooltip var when I draw the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can somewhat mitigate the issue by inserting the following into tooltip...

```
close: function( event, ui ) {
    $(".ui-tooltip").hide();
}
```

While the div's are supposed to hide on close, adding this code hides all the  ui-tooltip div's. when one closes.  I've tested this on the fiddle referenced in the original message and the results are good.